# Initiating Non-waiting Background Process in Perl

Tags: perl, system, exec, background-process

I have a Perl script that needs to kick off another process in the background and exit without waiting for the other script to finish. There are lots of threads on StackOverflow that cover how to wait in Perl or how to not wait for other programming languages, but I can't seem to find the right answer for Perl.

I've read up quite a bit and thought I was doing the right things but none of my attempts seem to be working correctly. Here are all the variations I've tried so far to no avail:

```
system(qq|perl /util/script.pl $id|);

system(qq|perl /util/script.pl $id &|);

exec(qq|perl /util/script.pl $id|);

exec(qq|perl /util/script.pl $id &|);
```

With each of these the parent process continues to wait for the child to finish before exiting. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong and the right way to fork the background process.

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

Full code to help with debugging. Note that the API->Function() calls are object oriented modules our code base uses for specific functions that database interactions, etc:

```
sub Add {
    my $self = shift;
    my $domain = shift;

    if(!$self->IsValid($domain)) { return; }

    my $SQL = qq| insert into domains set added=NOW(),domain=| . API->Database->Quote($domain);
    my $sth = API->DatabaseQuery($SQL);

    $SQL = qq| select last_insert_id() |;
    $sth = API->DatabaseQuery($SQL);
    my $id = $sth->fetchrow_array();

    my $command = qq|perl /home/siteuser/util/new.pl $id &|;
    system($command);

    return {'id'=>$id,'domain'=>$domain};
}
```

Comment: The parent is waiting for the IO in the child to be closed. Use (or at least look at) Proc::Daemon and 'perldoc -q daemon' on how to disassociate the parent from child.

Comment: You going to 'accept' any answer here?

Answer (score 4):

The first one is designed to work that way - `system` executes the command and finishes for it to end.

The last two are also designed that way - `exec` specifically is designed to never return. It basically replaces the parent process with the child process.

However, the second one should do the trick: the command launched from the `system` call is shell, which is given your string to execute. Since the string ends with "&", that means the shell will launch your command as a background process, and finish its own execution after that launch.

Can you please post more code illustrating how #2 didn't work?

Also, see what happens if you try backticks or qx:

```
my $output = qx|perl /util/script.pl $id &|;
print $output;
```

Also, as a way of reducing unknowns, can you please run the following and tell me what prints:

```
my $output = qx|(echo "AAAAAAA"; /bin/date; sleep 5; /bin/date; echo "BBBBBBB") &|;
print $output;
```

Comment: Merely for the sake of completeness, here's the somewhat relevant perlfaq entry: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-start-a-process-in-the-background?

Comment: I don't think your example will return any useful output.

Comment: @DVK - I thought the second one was correct as well but the script is definitely waiting on the child process to finish. If I comment out the system() line the parent script exits almost immediately and with that line it takes 3-4 seconds to exit which is how long the child takes to execute. I tried qx and I also tried backticks but neither ended up running the child at all. I'm not sure what else I can provide to help with troubleshooting. Any ideas?

Comment: @Matt - you're correct. The qx|| example doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Matt Kane - it's meant to return the usual shell background output (e.g. PID of backgrounded processs). It might need STDERR redirection - no xtterm in front of me right now so I don't recall if "&" output goes to stdout.

Comment: @Russell - could you please post your exact code? There may be some weird wrinkle in like a script name or something.

Comment: @Russell - I added a sample code I'd like you to try running, could you please report the results? Also, please verify what the value of `$id` is

Comment: @DVK - here is the output from the qx|| call you requested: AAAAAAA Mon Dec 13 10:57:12 PST 2010 Mon Dec 13 10:57:17 PST 2010 BBBBBBB

Comment: @Russell - please do `print Data::Dumper->Dump([$id])` as well.

Comment: @DVK - $id field is simply a string of the form 100000. The dumper output is $VAR1 = '100000';

Answer (score 3):

Are you calling `fork()` before calling `system` or `exec`?

```
my $pid = fork();
if (defined($pid) && $pid==0) {
    # background process
    my $exit_code = system( $command );
    exit $exit_code >> 8;
}


my $pid = fork();
if (defined($pid) && $pid==0) {
    # background process
    exec( $command );
    # doesn't^H^H^H^H^H^H shouldn't return
}
```

Comment: @mobrule - I'm not using fork(). Which of the above is the right one to kick off a background process that the parent doesn't wait on? I'm assuming it is the one that uses system().

Comment: They are both roughly equivalent.

Comment: @mobrul/@Matt - Both are still causing the parent to wait. Any ideas how to modify so that the parent doesn't wait?

Comment: The right way is to use `fork()` to create a background process, then to run `system` or `exec` from that background process.

Comment: (Since this is Perl, I should have started that last comment with "A right way ...")

Comment: @mobrule - So why is this still blocking the parent once we make the system call?

Answer (score 3):

You need to disassociate the child from the parent.
See perldoc -q daemon. Or [Proc::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Proc-Daemon)

Comment: I don't want to run it as a deamon. I just want to kick it off are a separate process as necessary. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Russell C. - you don't need to run as a "forever" daemon - simply start as one, do your work and exit. There's absolutely nothing that's technically demanding that daemon runs forever. +1

Answer (score 0):

Using fork is a good way to background processes:

```
my $pid = fork;
die "fork failed" unless defined $pid;
if ($pid == 0) {
    # child process goes here
    do '/util/script.pl';
    exit;
}
# parent process continues here
```

Comment: I just tested this and the parent is still waiting in this case.

Comment: That is strange.  Are you sure you put the exit statement inside the child block?

Comment: I did. The whole thing is very strange indeed. That is why I posted here. Any other ideas what might be going on?

Comment: I would suggest you replace /util/script.pl with a simple program such as:
    for (1 .. 10) { print "sleeping $_ ...\n"; sleep 1 }
This may help you debug the issue.